# Class are not working on pre tag in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a class on pre tag using javascript, i tried this code..

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';

?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Post-Question</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="code-prettify-master/loader/prettify.css"/>
    <style>

    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header"></div>
    <div class="well-lg col-md-6">
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['sucess']))
        {?>
           <span class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $_SESSION['sucess'];?></span>
        <?php
            unset($_SESSION['sucess']);
        }
        elseif(isset($_SESSION['error']))
        {?>
        <span class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $_SESSION['error'];?></span>
        <?php
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }

        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-lg">
        Post Your Question Here!
    </div>

    <div class="col--md-6">
        <form action="ques.php" method="post">

            <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Enter your issue here" class="form-control"><br>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <span class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span></span>
               <span class="btn">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-italic"></span></span>
                 <span class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link">   </span></span>
               <span class="btn"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">   </span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">



            <textarea class="form-control" name="desc" placeholder="Iuuse Description">

            </textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        </form>
    </div>
        </div>
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $smt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM qa");
    $smt->execute();
    while($rows=$smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):?>

     <div class="h2"> <?php echo $rows->QUES; ?>!</div>
        <div class="h4"><pre><code><?php echo htmlentities($rows->ANS); ?></code></pre></div>
    <?php endwhile;?>


</div>
</div>




</div>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
      // var pro=document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
        $('pre code').addClass('prettyprint');
    });

</script>

<script src="code-prettify-master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i use another class insted of prettyprint, then the code works and also if i use the prettyprint class like `<pre class="prettyprint">` then it will works, but i want to use it useing the js method.[I am using this plugin](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md)

Comment: So which one is it then, `prettyprint`, `prettfyprint` or `prettifyprint`? Please pay attention to spelling.

Comment: the spelling has been corrected, please check it now.

Comment: Please post a *new* question if you have another problem. Your initial question was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no point in having `<code>` in `<pre>` in your html as it may screw up your syntax highlight:

```
<div class="h4"><pre><?php echo htmlentities($rows->ANS); ?></pre></div>
```

If your intention is to add a class to `pre`: do it with `$('pre').addClass('prettyprint');`; if you want prettyprint syntax highlight to work on these `pre`s, just in case, run the prettyprint script after you have added the class to the the `pre`s.

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $('pre code').addClass('prettyprint');
        $.getScript( "code-prettify-master/loader/run_prettify.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
           console.log("prettified");
           });
});
```

although [it should work just fine like this](http://jsfiddle.net/okah1s8v/1/).

If you are using `prettify.js` instead of `run_prettify.js`, you need to call `prettyPrint()` [in this manner](http://jsfiddle.net/19gh30jr/3/).

If you want attach an on-click event for some `<b></b>`, you should give it a class first: `<b class="click_this_old_sport"> hey jude</b>` then in simply do this in jQuery:

```
 $(".click_this_old_sport").click(function(){ alert("clicked!") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you have some thing to do

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // var pro=document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
    $('pre').addClass('prettyprint');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Class name  prettyprint you are using in code is wrong. It should be prettifyprint. Change your code to

```
$('pre code').addClass('prettifyprint');
```

It should work